# LaTeX throws error on \heightof

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

I'm trying use `\heightof` in my document but XeLaTeX throws an error. Both minimal code end errors are below. Ubuntu 20.04 with latest updates

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum height=\heightof{A}]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 
                                                  
l.6 \node[minimum height=\heightof{A}]{A};
```

UPD. The height of bold text is `height("{\textbf{A}}")`.

Comment: `\heightof` works only in `\setlength` or similar commands... try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\heightof{A}
\end{document}` and get a surprise ;-)...

Comment: Thanks, that cleared things a bit

Answer (score 6):

`\heighof` doesn't work inside tikz, use the functions provided by it. See the section "Mathematical Expressions" in the documentation.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum height=height("A")]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Addition: `minimum height` does not describe the height of the node content, in the sense of the height of a TeX box, but the total height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,inner sep=0,minimum height=10pt] (A) {.};

\draw[red,<->] ([xshift=-2pt]A.south west) --++ (0,10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum height=10pt] (A) {.};

\draw[red,<->] ([xshift=-2pt]A.south west) --++ (0,10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `draw` and with `x` in the node instead of `A`.

Comment: @egreg that is not related to the height function, but that `minimum height` doesn't set the "height" but the "totalheight".

Comment: Thanks, especially for particular section of manual. But the problem didn't solve. The code `\node[minimum height=height(\noexpand\textbf{"A"}), draw=black]{A};` throws error. The difference in "depth" is insignificant but the height should be measure of bold text

Answer (score 1):

The command `\heightof` only works in `calc` package expressions.

You can use `height{"A"}`, but this wouldn't take care of the `inner sep`, so you should add it to the minimum height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum height=height("A")+2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep})]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum height=height("A")+2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep})]{x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=1pt]
\node[draw,minimum height=height("A")+2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep})]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=1pt]
\node[draw,minimum height=height("A")+2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep})]{x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if one sets inner sep to zero, it still doesn't encompass the A: `\node[draw,inner sep=0,minimum height=height("A")+2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep})]{\smash{A}};`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The height is set correctly, The node contents is placed so that it lies at the vertical middle of the node; if the object has zero height…

Comment: Thanks, the `inner sep` issue was easier. Additional condition is the code `\node[minimum height=height(\noexpand\textbf{"A"}), draw=black]{A};` trow error

Comment: @Alet I'm afraid that only simple strings are accepted by `inner sep`; besides, `\textbf` would do no good because inside a Ti*k*Z picture all fonts are set to `\nullfont`.